# Spring Integration Xpath Filter with Regex

Tags: spring, xpath, filter, spring-integration

I am using an Xpath Filter to filter out some incoming events.

This is my sample input xml. I need to filter by the value of fieldC, by allowing events that have a fieldC value of 1,2,3,6 or 7.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<add>
<doc>
<field name="fieldA">453.97</field>
<field name="fieldB">278.25</field>
<field name="fieldC">3</field>
<field name="fieldD">Agent</field>
<field name="fieldE">Mobile Site</field>
<field name="fieldF">Cancel</field>
<field name="fieldG">2015-09-14T13:17:21.000Z</field>
</doc>
</add>
```

Xpath Tried: 
 
/add/doc/field[@name='fieldC']/text() 
/add/doc/field[@name='fieldC']

```
<int:chain input-channel="channelIn" output-channel="channelOut">
 <int-xml:xpath-filter id="filterEvents" match-value="3" match-type="exact">
    <int-xml:xpath-expression expression="/add/doc/field[@name='fieldC']/text()" />
    </int-xml:xpath-filter>
 </int-xml:xpath-filter>
</int:chain>
```

Filter by match-type 'exact' works, but I am not able to get the same working with regex.

Regex Tried: /^(1|2|3|6|7)$/

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex has bad syntax; lose the `/`s...

```
match-value="^(1|2|3|6|7)$" match-type="regex"
```

...works fine for me.

Comment: It is customary here to 'accept' an answer if it solves your problem - it will help others searching for questions/answers. Click the check/tick mark under the vote counter to the left.